# Continue odd/even striping across grouped fields?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 and views 3.20, `unformatted list`, choosing a grouping field and selecting **Add striping (odd/even), first/last row classes** .

My views output is currently grouped by first letter:

A
 aa (odd)
 ab (even)
 ac (odd)
B
 ba (odd)

but i'd like the striping to continue across the grouping, so "ba" is even - i can resort to js but i'm sure there's a proper way i should be doing this.. thanks!